# what is the index to measure the credit volatility

Tags: volatility, credit-derivatives

Similar to VIX to measure the equity vol and Move for rates vol, is there a simple index to measure the credit vol

Comment: Volx https://products.markit.com/indices/iTraxx/CreditVolatilityIndices.asp are realized, rather than implied volatilities. People do trade swaption on CDX IG, CDX HY, and similar EUR indices quite a bit. You should be able to find implied volatility quotes inexpensively, but no a "free" official credit implied volatility index yet.

Answer (score 3):

The CBOE has recently launched four new daily measures of implied volatility for [CDX NAM IG (VIXIG - North American investment grade)](https://www.spglobal.com/spdji/en/indices/fixed-income/cdx-cboe-na-investment-grade-1-month-volatility-index-bp-volatility/), [CDX NAM HY (VIXHY - North American high yield)](https://www.spglobal.com/spdji/en/indices/fixed-income/cdx-cboe-na-high-yield-1-month-volatility-index-bp-volatility), [VIXIE iTraxx Europe Main](https://www.spglobal.com/spdji/en/indices/fixed-income/itraxx-cboe-europe-main-1-month-volatility-index-bp-volatility), [VIXXO iTraxx Europe Crossover](https://www.spglobal.com/spdji/en/indices/fixed-income/itraxx-cboe-europe-crossover-1-month-volatility-index-bp-volatility).

Press release: https://www.spglobal.com/spdji/en/documents/index-news-and-announcements/20231003-spdji-cboe-credit-vix-indices-launch.pdf